# "Extend" parent pom <build> in a child pom to add some additional plugins I would like to execute

Tags: maven, plugins, build

I'm currently using a parent `<build>` that is convenient for 75% of my projects.
it's rather complete. Let's call it **'A'** :

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Bug Eclipse temporaire -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Compilation classique -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <charset>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</charset>
                    <docencoding>${maven.test.compile.encoding}</docencoding>

                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>${maven-compiler.memory}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin Surefire : exécution tests unitaires -->
            <!-- Tous les tests sauf ceux débutant par IT* -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>

                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xmx20g</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin Failsafe : exécution de tests d'intégration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx20g</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Javadoc plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Source plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Release -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Deploy plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

However beginning at a sub project, and for many modules below, 25% of them, there's a need to extend their `<build>` with the execution of few plugins, while those in the parent `pom.xml` should continue executing. Here they are, in this **'B'** part :

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.0</version>
                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        
                        <configuration>
                            <recompileMode>all</recompileMode>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        
                        <configuration>
                            <recompileMode>all</recompileMode>
                            <testSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I would like them to add them to the others already executed by the parent pom.

How may I avoid a `pom.xml` with **A** + **B** plugins stacked ? Do I have a way in a child `pom.xml` to '*patch*' my parent `<build>` with the additional plugins I would like it to execute ?

Said another way, **I don't want** to have this in my child pom :

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Bug Eclipse temporaire -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Compilation classique -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <charset>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</charset>
                    <docencoding>${maven.test.compile.encoding}</docencoding>

                    <forkMode>once</forkMode>
                    <argLine>${maven-compiler.memory}</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin Surefire : exécution tests unitaires -->
            <!-- Tous les tests sauf ceux débutant par IT* -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>

                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>

                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xmx20g</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Plugin Failsafe : exécution de tests d'intégration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <argLine>-Xmx20g</argLine>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Javadoc plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>
                    <charset>UTF-8</charset>
                    <docencoding>UTF-8</docencoding>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Source plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Release -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Deploy plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.0</version>
                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        
                        <configuration>
                            <recompileMode>all</recompileMode>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        
                        <configuration>
                            <recompileMode>all</recompileMode>
                            <testSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Currently from what I see, know and experienced, creating a `<build>` section in a child `pom.xml` overrides entirely the `<build>` section of the parent pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not repeat anything from the parent POM. The build sections of parent and child are automatically merged, so it is enough to specify the *additional* plugins or executions in the child POM.

If you have a look at the effective POM (e.g. through your IDE or with the maven help plugin), you can see the merged version of your `<build>` section.

Comment: Your right ! It's another issue that led me to a wrong analysis of my trouble !
Thanks